# html tags built inside java string are not detected in browser

Tags: java, html, string, browser

I want to send a java string to an external service which will print the message as is on a browser html page. So, I have built some html into that string, something like "< a href = \" url\">WORKFLOW< /a>" hoping this would be detected by browser. But it is not detecting and when do inspect and see using edit as html , tags are decoded to different symbols like '<' to '&lt ;' etc.

How can I build my Html in java string and post in such a way that it will be detected by the browser?

Comment: Well, first off, in your code, `"<a href = "` will be one string, because of the `"`. Change that to `"< a href = \" url\">WORKFLOW< /a>"`

Comment: It sounds like the external service is encoding those character to prevent you from writing HTML, which is a pretty good idea from a security point of view. So you're trying to do something that the external service doesn't want you to do.